# AdBannerView removeFromSuperview

Tags: ios, ios8, iad, adbannerview

I am trying to remove a "AddBannerView" that has been created in a Storyboard and referenced in the `UIViewController` in this way:

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet ADBannerView *banner;
```

The problem is that when I call `[self.banner removeFromSuperview]` nothing happens (I have connected the banner with the controller so that is not the problem).

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Is the banner not being recreated again after you call removeFromSuperview somehow?

Answer (score 0):

use these code instead of `removerFromSuperview`

```
[self.banner cancelBannerViewAction]
```

It Cancels an executing banner view action.